# Auto forwarding between slack channels

Tags: slack

Is there a way to auto forward from one slack channel to another, based on the message content?

I want to have messages that contain a certain string, in one channel, to automatically forward to a different channel.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a bit too broad for this format, but here is a general answer: Yes. You can make a Slack app that receives messages from one channel using the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) and then sending a copy to the other channel with the web API method [post.chatMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)

Comment: @ErikKalkoken He meant an already app or pre-built bot to dot this. Of course we can create a slack app to do this.

Comment: Since this is a forum for programming I think its fair to assume all questions are about that topic if OP does not say otherwise.